# Clarification on html scraping with python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml

I'm teaching myself how to get information from websites, and I'm confused on how to actually use lxml to do so. Say I wanted to print the titles of the contents of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) wikipedia page. I would first:

```
site=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics')
tree=html.fromstring(site.content)
```

but now I don't know which is the correct xpath to put in. I naively highlighted the contents block on the page and I simply put

```
contents=tree.xpath('//*[@id="toc"]/div/h2')
```

which of course doens't give me what I want. (I get an empty array). How do I do this?

Comment: If your actual goal is to extract information from Wikipedia, use [the api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia).

Comment: Your code works correctly for me, when I include it in a complete sample program. Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information. [Here's my sample program](https://ideone.com/BlLsWx) The result is `[<Element h2 at 0x7f7a3c2cbef8>]`.

Comment: Since all the data you would want is in the `tree` var, it seems like you you just need to know the proper location of the information you are trying to extract.  You can use the developers tools of your browser to get the xpath or you can go over the raw page source to find the info you need and craft the xpath.  This document helped me a lot trying to navigate through lxml:  http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very clear. I can't seem to extract the actual information e.g when I add an /text(), I don't get the contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import html 
import requests
site=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics')
tree=html.fromstring(site.content)
contents=tree.xpath('//*[@id="toc"]/div/h2/text()')[0]
print(contents)
```

You can test xpath in chrome.Open 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics' in chrome,then press F12.In console,input `$x('//*[@id="toc"]/div/h2/')`,there would output h2 element.If you want to show the content of h2,the xpath should be `$x('//*[@id="toc"]/div/h2/text()')`,the result is array of content.

Comment: please add some description

Comment: Please do not only dump code, but try to explain as well why this solves the problem. Read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want the parent titles, if you analyze the structure you have:

`//div[@id="toc"]/ul/li/a/span[@class="toctext"]` this path reaches all the titles, so for retrieve all, the code will be:

```
from lxml import html 
import requests
site=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics')
tree=html.fromstring(site.content)
contents=tree.xpath('//div[@id="toc"]/ul/li/a/span[@class="toctext"]/text()')
print(contents)
```

Where the output is:

```
['Overview', "Deriving Hamilton's equations", 'As a reformulation of Lagrangian mechanics', 'Geometry of Hamiltonian systems', 'Generalization to quantum mechanics through Poisson bracket', 'Mathematical formalism', 'Riemannian manifolds', 'Sub-Riemannian manifolds', 'Poisson algebras', 'Charged particle in an electromagnetic field', 'Relativistic charged particle in an electromagnetic field', 'See also', 'References', 'External links']
```

But if you want to have also the child titles, you can get all the li and iterate:

```
import requests
import json
from lxml import html 
site=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics')
tree=html.fromstring(site.content)
contents=tree.xpath('//div[@id="toc"]/ul/li')
title_dic = {}
for content in contents:
    subcontents = content.xpath('ul/li/a/span[@class="toctext"]/text()')
    title_dic[content.xpath('a/span[@class="toctext"]/text()')[0]] = subcontents
print(json.dumps(title_dic, indent = 4))
```

And the output is:

```
{
    "Overview": [
        "Basic physical interpretation",
        "Calculating a Hamiltonian from a Lagrangian"
    ],
    "Deriving Hamilton's equations": [],
    "As a reformulation of Lagrangian mechanics": [],
    "Geometry of Hamiltonian systems": [],
    "Generalization to quantum mechanics through Poisson bracket": [],
    "Mathematical formalism": [],
    "Riemannian manifolds": [],
    "Sub-Riemannian manifolds": [],
    "Poisson algebras": [],
    "Charged particle in an electromagnetic field": [],
    "Relativistic charged particle in an electromagnetic field": [],
    "See also": [],
    "References": [
        "Footnotes",
        "Sources"
    ],
    "External links": []
}
```

And you have the parent titles as the keys of the dictionary, and the values ​​are the children if they exist.